# Specifying Client secrets in JwtBearerOptions for Azure Active Directory authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

If I create a new ASP.NET Core MVC application in Visual Studio 2017, I can add client secrets with one line to `AzureAdServiceCollectionExtensions`:

```cs
public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
    // Add this line below
    options.ClientSecret = _azureOptions.ClientSecret;
    options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
}
```

The configuration POCO is already wired up to take it from the config file.

On the other hand, in Web API projects, authentication uses JWT Tokens and the code generated by Visual Studio is different:

```cs
public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
{
    options.Audience = _azureOptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
}
```

I'm not sure where in the `JwtBearOptions` to put the client secret.

Comment: Does it work? Did you try it?

Comment: Why not in the configure method?

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually specify the client secret in the options.  It's used when you sign the token using the symmetric key.

```cs
public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
{
    options.Audience = _azureOptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
    var secretKey = "mysupersecret_secretkey!123";
    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));
    options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = signingKey;
}
```

Check out these links:

- http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2017/09/06/secure-web-api-in-asp-net-core/
- https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

The OIDC handler allows you to specify the client secret since it can fetch access tokens by itself if you want that.

The JWT handler does not offer this capability. Its job is to validate JSON Web Tokens and do nothing more.

If you want to get a delegated access token to make calls as the user to some other APIs, you will need to get the access token with ADAL/MSAL yourself.

You would use the `OnTokenValidated` callback for that:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
            }
        };
    });
```